# How to use template inside a form in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a vue instance for the form

```
var formObject =  new Vue({
    el: '#amount_form',
    data: {
        logdate: '',
        amount:'',
        description:''
    },
      methods: {
        processForm :function(event)
        {
            var data = {"logdate":this.logdate,"amount":parseFloat(this.amount),"description":this.description};
            console.log(data);

            var parameters =
                {
                    "data":data,
                    "url":"save",
                    "type":"post",
                    "data_type":"JSON",
                    "callback":function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
                sendDataToSErver(parameters);
        }
    }
});
```

i have a template for categories

```
var categorySelect = Vue.component('category-select',
    {
        data()
        {
            return{
                options:[],
                cat:""
                }},
        template:'<select class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model="cat">' +
            '       <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option></select>',
        created :function()
        {
            var templateObject = this;
            var parameters =
                    {

                        "url":"getCategories",
                        "type":"GET",
                        "async":true,
                        "data_type":"JSON",
                        "callback":function(data)
                        {
                            templateObject.options = data;
                        }
                    }
                sendDataToSErver(parameters);
        }
    });
```

i am using this template inside the form

```
    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="log_date" class="sr-only">Date</label>
                                    <input v-model="logdate" type="datetime-local" id="log_date" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="amount" class="sr-only">Amount</label>
                                    <input v-model="amount"  type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="category" class="sr-only">Category</label>
                                    <category-select></category-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label  for="description" class="sr-only">Description</label>
                                    <textarea v-model="description" class="form-control" id="description" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Now  how can get the value in form.

Answer (score 1):

You can [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) an event from the child. The parent needs to listen for the custom event and get the data from there. You also need to listen for `onChange` on your select to `emit` the event.

The template for categories should be something like this

```
var categorySelect = Vue.component('category-select',
{
    data()
    {
        return {
            options:[],
            cat:""
        }
    },
    template:'<select class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model="cat" @change="handleUpdateSelectedValue($event)">' +
        '       <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option></select>',
    methods: {
     handleUpdateSelectedValue(event) {
       this.$emit('selectedValue', event.target.value) //emitting the event here
     }
    }
    created :function()
    {
        var templateObject = this;
        var parameters =
                {

                    "url":"getCategories",
                    "type":"GET",
                    "async":true,
                    "data_type":"JSON",
                    "callback":function(data)
                    {
                        templateObject.options = data;
                    }
                }
            sendDataToSErver(parameters);
    }
});
```

And now you need to listen for the event in the parent

```
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="sr-only">Category</label>
    <category-select @selectedValue="handleSelectedValue"></category-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the only thing that remains to do is to define `handleSelectedValue` in your parent component and do something with that value.

```
var formObject =  new Vue({
 el: '#amount_form',
 data: {
    logdate: '',
    amount:'',
    description:''
 },
 methods: {
  handleSelectedValue(value) {
  }
 }
 ...
```